# Send a model when I click a button in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ienumerable

I need to send the current `@Model` to my `Index` action when I click the following button:

```
@model IEnumerable<Licencias>

code here....

<div class="form-group px-xl-3" data-select2-id="29">
    <label style="visibility: hidden;">Previous</label>
    <a asp-area="Reports" asp-controller="Points" asp-action="Index" type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" style="border-radius: 2rem">Next></a>
</div>
```

I'd like to get the data in my `PointController`:

```
public IActionResult Index(IEnumerable<Licencias> licencias)
{
    var result = GetInfoPuntosPorSubestacion();
    return View(result);
}
```

I tried to send the data through `asp-route-licencias="@Model"` but `asp-route` just allowed me to send a string

```
<div class="form-group px-xl-3" data-select2-id="29">
    <label style="visibility: hidden;">Previous</label>
    <a asp-area="Reports" asp-controller="Points" asp-action="Index" type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" style="border-radius: 2rem">Next></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Luis, What is the `@Model`, if you want to get what you changed for the model, it is not possible. If you just want to pass the current model it rendered, you can use something like `@Html.ActionLink("Next", "ActionName", "ControllerName",new { id = Model.TagId, name = Model.Name })`.